# Notepad++ regex to find 3 consecutive numbers

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use Notepadd++ to find all occurrences of width=xxx so I can change them to width="xxx"

as far as I have got is width=[^\n] which only selects width=x

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you need exactly 3 numbers, the following is tested in Notepad++:

```
width=\d\d\d[^\d]
```

Reading further into your requirement, you can use the tagging feature:

```
Find what:    width=(\d\d\d)([^\d])
Replace with: width="\1"\2
```

Here, the (n) bracketed portions of the regex are stored (in sequence) as \1,\2,...\n which can be referred to in the replacement field.

As a regex engine, Notepad++ is poor. [Here](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) is a description of what's supported. Pretty basic.

Comment: So it doesn't support `{3}` but it does support negating character classes (which isn't always supported?) what sort of "Regular Expressions" craziness did they put in Notepad++???

Comment: Though it does support \d, which isn't listed on that page, so I suspect that page is inaccurate and out of date. I've used \s+ and \t.

Comment: The width="\1"\2 replace leaves width="", so it looks like the \1 does not return any digits

Comment: sorry I didnt alter my search to width=(\d\d\d). Thank you all!

Comment: I was 3 seconds off, arg! At least it worked for you, god that was a bitch.

Comment: Working great here. np++5.1.1

Comment: Had to work for me with grouping and I am using Notepad++ v5.6.8

Comment: quick note, this limitation no longer applies - as of version 6, Notepad++ supports (uses?) PCRE - the perl-compatible regular expressions library; as far a I can tell, that quickly elevates it from one of the worst levels of regexp support to top-notch support!

Comment: Added Your comment as separate answer.

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the [Notepad++ Regular Expression list](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions) there does not seem to support the `{n}` notation to match `n` characters, so `\d{3}` did not work.

However, what had worked for me and may be considered a hack was: `\d\d\d`

Tested in Notepad++ and has worked, for the Find field use `(\d\d\d)` and for the Replace filed use `"\1"\2`.

Comment: This was a success width=\d\d\d, but I'm at loss on what to set the replace to to preserve the 3 numbers

Answer (score 11):

As Tao commented, as of version 6, Notepad++ supports PCRE.

So now You can write:

```
\d{1,5}
```

Comment: I tested in 6.3, it says "Incorrect regular expression"... It should be `\d{1,5}`

Comment: Awesome! Just what I'm looking for. Use `\d{10}`, for example, to find a string of 10 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
/(width=)(\d+?)/gim
```

Because you may want variable digits. Some widths may be 8, or 15, or 200, or whatever.

If you want to specify a range, you do it like this:

```
/(width=)(\d{1,3)/gim
```

where the 1 represents the lower limit and the 3 represents the upper.

I grouped both parts of the expression, so when you replace you can keep the first part and not blow it away.

Answer (score 2):

Tried it: replace `width=([0-9][0-9][0-9])` with `width="\1"` and worked fine... Of course might not be best syntax to do this but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I would try this one: `width=(\d{3,})`, and check *Regular expression*, and also *. matches newline*

works for me on ver: 7.5.4